# Efficient DIV structure for a grid layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been developing a website where, now i need to show sort of a grid layout ( This is not regarding the grid structure which is used to maintain the whole web page layout ) with options in it! Below is a mock up of the layout I'm suppose to implement.

[image: mockup]

How can I achieve this with html. I thought of using a real html table, bt since tables are not in use these days for layouts, I'm not sure if it's the bes way. Is it good to use a div structure and achieve this using css or what is the best way to implement such a layout.

Comment: I don't see a problem with using a table in this instance. Tables are a dated if you were to build a whole site with one but as for sections and content of a site they are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information you're presenting is semantically tabular; HTML tables are exactly what you should use.

Tables are frowned upon for layout, they are preferred when presenting tabular data.

I'd recommend looking up the `thead` and `tfoot` elements to aid in the markup semantics.

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely appropriate use for an HTML table.

Tables shouldn't be used to layout a document, but this is a genuine table: the cells within each row are related, and the cells within each column are related, and those relationships are labeled with column and row headers. That's an HTML table.

And incidentally, you'll find that using an HTML table is a very efficient way to mark this up verses using other elements like divs, in terms of both DOM complexity and overall file size.